# Docker: PostgresSQL - An error occurred using the connection to database

Tags: postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to run a demo ASP.NET Core with PostgresSQL in Docker, but the Database connection is failing.

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
> An error occurred using the connection to database 'ToDoApp' on server
> 'tcp://postgresserver:5432'.
>
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
>
> An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for
> context type 'Postgress_ASPNETCore.Db.ToDoContext'.
>
> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 3D000: database "ToDoApp" does
> not exist

**appsettings.json**

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "ToDoDb": "User ID=postgres;Password=password;Host=postgresserver;Port=5432;Database=ToDoApp;Pooling=true;"
 }
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services: 
    aspnetcore:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        links:
            - postgresserver
        depends_on:
            - "postgresserver"
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
        networks: 
            - todoapp-network

    postgresserver:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
              POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        volumes:
                - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks: 
                - todoapp-network

networks: 
    todoapp-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    pgdata:
```

I am unable to figure out the issue. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am aware it must be a dumb question. I started learning docker from yesterday, and the tutorial had Postgres, so I installed that (for the very 1st time). Well `ToDoApp` exists in the local db server. I am unsure how to open it in the container server :"postgresserver"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `ToDoApp` database is not created on startup.

To do so you can add it as an environment variable to your docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services: 

...

    postgresserver:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        environment:
              POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
              POSTGRES_DB: ToDoApp
        volumes:
                - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks: 
                - todoapp-network
...
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, but it didn't help

Comment: Did it give the exact same error? Because that would be very strange. Also you can `docker exec -it postgresserver psql` to get into the postgresql cli and then `\l` to list all databases.

Comment: Yes, the same error. Anyways this is ef code first approach, so the database should get created even if it didn't exist.

Comment: Did you try listing the databases? What output did you get?

Comment: Can you help me how to get the list of dbs in "postgresserver" server. I can see it in localhost

Comment: You can `docker exec -it postgresserver psql -u <username> -p <password>` to get into the postgresql cli and then `\l` to list all databases.

Comment: Thanks, it is showing `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "pgsql": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Comment: it is `psql` not `pgsql`

Comment: I tied that first, the error was : `invalid option -- 'u'
Try "psql --help" for more information.`

Comment: Yes this is my bad. Actually try just `docker exec -it postgresserver psql` since you did not change the default username (it should be the default `root`). Otherwise add `-U <username>`

Comment: Got it, the db is not available

Comment: How did you refresh the docker images after changing the docker-compose.yml file? You should do `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up --force-recreate`

Comment: I see the issue now, if I name the container `postgresserverdb` in yml file, the container is getting created with name postgresserverdb_1

Comment: Yes, if you want to recreate firstly remove the old containers with `docker rm`

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for your patience. I am totally new in this